# General principles for attaining divine bliss

Tags: gayatri-mantra, vishnu-sahasranama, samadhi, purusha-sukta

I am aware that a similar [Question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24856/what-does-it-feel-like-to-be-god-realized/28568#28568) has already been asked, but my question is more about the how than what. I meditated once on Gayatri mantra (I was initiated into it a few years ago) for 30 minutes. After that meditation I felt a kind of bliss, which I feel sometimes in meditation or recitation of Vishnu Sahasranama or Purusha Suktam. I want to experience this more regularly, but I don't know exactly how to do it other than these methods. Are there generally a few principles one has to follow in order to experience this? One thing I think required is vairagya, the detachment. If I understand correctly one mustn't be attached to outcome, but if I meditate for this purpose am I not attached?